# How did Garak know that the Romulans won't question why a data rod was partially recoverable?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the episode [In the Pale Moonlight](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/In_the_Pale_Moonlight_(episode)), Vreenak says the following:

> VREENAK: You are persistent, Captain, I'll grant you that, but dogged determination isn't enough to change the reality of your situation. Time is definitely not on your side. **The Dominion shipyards are working at one hundred percent capacity.** Yours are still being rebuilt. **The Dominion is breeding legions of Jem'Hadar soldiers every day.** You're experiencing a manpower shortage. But most important, the Dominion is resolved to win the war at any cost. You and I both know the Federation has already put out peace feelers. Now, in all candor, if you were in my position, which side would you choose?

From this we know that the Dominion have more than enough soldiers and ships to conduct missions.

When Sisko confronts Garak, he says:

> GARAK: Oh, but I think that there is. You see, **when the Tal Shiar
> finishes examining the wreckage of Vreenak's shuttle, they'll find the
> burnt remnants of a Cardassian optolythic data rod which somehow
> miraculously survived the explosion. After painstaking forensic
> examination, they'll discover that the rod contains a recording of a
> high level Dominion meeting at which the invasion of Romulus was being
> planned.**
>
> SISKO: And then they'll discover that it is a fraud!
>
> GARAK: **No, I don't think they will, because any imperfections in the forgery
> will appear to be a result of the explosion.** So, with a seemingly
> legitimate rod in one hand and a dead senator in the other, I ask you,
> Captain, what conclusion would you draw?

How did Garak know the Romulans won't suspect why a data rod was partially recoverable? Garak hopes the Romualans will come to the conclusion the Dominion killed Vreenak to supress information about a Dominion invasion, but they left a data rod?

If your plan is to cleanup any evidence, won't you make sure it was done correctly and made unrecoverable?

Comment: It's hard to think through stuff like that when one of your hands is holding a data rod, and the other is somehow managing to maintain a grasp on a Romulan senator's dead body. Those dudes are heavy!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I agree, but the Romulans are smart and devious, so I would assume at least one Romulan would have a suspicion.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - The more I think about it, another point comes to mind. In Garak's plan, no indication is given that the Dominion is aware of the data rod, only that Vreenak knew information, but not that it was stored on a data rod.

Comment: Garak is guessing, based in his extensive knowledge of Romulan operational procedures

Comment: @Valorum - Pretty big guess on his part. Meh, I already got downvoted. I guess because the question is unanswerable.

Comment: @nsonline89 - You might get lucky and find a cast or crew interview, or a note in the script but the short answer is that it's just part of the narrative arc that Garak knew this could happen and has *plans on top of plans*, like any good superspy.

Comment: the issue isn't whether the data was recoverable. The issue is that, even though they used a master forger, Vrenak was still able to determine of the rod: "it's a faaaakeee!" What Garak is saying is that, the imperfections in the recording that were a give away to Vrenak will appear as expected corruption of the data due to the explosion. Vrenak's death and an apparently legitimate data rod will lead the Romulans to believe the data on the rod. The ship went boom. It's not unreasonable to think the Dominion would see that, say 'mission accomplished' and not try to scrape the rubble for the rod

Comment: @NKCampbell - Right, but if the Dominion wanted to suppress the information, why didn't they do a more better job? They clearly had the resources to do it. Given how deceptive the Romulans are, I figured at least one of them would question why a data rod was left. Given the first comment and yours, I guess Garak pushed them in the direction he wanted, I hoped for the best.

Comment: @nsonline89 - The implication is that the Dominion have a spy/saboteur on the station. Don't forget that DS9 is still in Federation space at this point and 'doing a better job' isn't in the Dominion's capacity. - *"preliminary report points to sabotage.*"

Comment: @Valorum - Ah! I see. +1. I didn't realize that, but you're right.

Comment: Actually the real plot hole is that Garak's plan only works because the Senator doesn't immediately file a report on how FAAAAAKE the data rod is prior to leaving the station.  But this is a universe where people hand off iPads in person for reports.

Comment: sounds like it's loosely based on operation mincemeat from ww2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Mincemeat - use a dead body and make it seem they are incredibly lucky to get the data so they don't question it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garak is behind the sabotage. He has clearly given some considerable thought to both the method of killing Vreenak, and the preservation of the rod as evidence that will "*somehow miraculously [survive] the explosion*" at the scene of the incident.

His plan is predicated on a number of key elements;

**That he knows what forensic assessment the Romulans will perform on the shuttle and that he can confidently fake a *style* of sabotage that the Romulans will assume to be conducted by the Dominion, possibly because of a [distinctive use of certain explosives or detonators](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Molecular_decay_detonator).**

> **WORF:** *Senator Vreenak. He was returning to Romulus from a diplomatic
> mission to Soukara when his shuttle exploded. The Tal Shiar are
> investigating, but **preliminary report points to sabotage. They believe
> that the Dominion is responsible.***

**That he's confident that the rod will survive the explosion (noting that he can be reasonably sure where Vreenak will store it and that it's in a container that will survive the explosion) but also that it will be sufficiently impacted as to potentially have flaws.**

> **Garak:** *After painstaking forensic examination, they'll discover that the rod contains a recording of a high level Dominion meeting at which the invasion of Romulus was being planned.*

None of this is beyond the capacity of someone with access to a high-powered simulator, knowledge of Romulan ship operations, control over [what the rod is stored in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TADce.png), and a strong understanding of explosives, all of which Garak has in spades.

Comment: I'm wondering if Garak, given that he had access to the Romulan ship, *pre-damaged the rod*, then put it somewhere that wouldn't be affected by the explosion.

Comment: That's possible, because an explosion could inadvertently destroy the rod. He probably damaged it, and hid it on the ship. A better question is, how did he get it on board without the Romulans knowing? According to him, they won't notice him anywhere near the ship. Beam it? Doesn't he need clearance to go to OPs or even access an runabout?

Comment: @nsonline89 - I'm assuming he either sneaked on board or transported something on board. Sisko doesn't ask and Garak doesn't say. I'm sure he can wangle the use of a transporter if he needs to, though.

Comment: Why the downvote? I clearly thought this was a good answer.

Comment: @nsonline89 - Both answers seem to have attracted a downvote, along with the original question. Probably it's the same person. I don't tend to worry about what individual users do.

Answer (score -1):

Garek would know from real world examples that governments like his own Cardassian government, the Romulans, Dominion, and we see in real world Nazis, Stalinst and Putin Russia - all misinformation campaigns follow the same rule book.

Specifically a variant of "Predictive projection." Predictive projection is a preemptive flying of a false flag. See for example...
https://www.politico.com/news/magazine/2022/03/22/putin-disinformation-apathy-00018974

As Garak states the data rod is suspicious and flawed.  An explosion will cover some of that but what tips the scales is the Romulans will assume betrayal because that is what they would do. (And the Cardassians too which is why Garak can make a good prediction- but what is shocking is everyone knows the Federation typically would not do this sort of thing. See below transcript.)

Valorum's answer neglects this. And as I read the question it is about why Garek thinks things - not the physics of data rods.

[Also, trivia I suspect most folks miss is that Garek was not using the biomemtic gel as a pricey black market item he was using it as the explosive.]

TRANSCRIPT from
http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/543.htm

> GARAK: Precisely. And the more the Dominion protests their innocence, the more the Romulans will believe they're guilty because it's exactly what the Romulans would have done in their place. That's why you came to me, isn't it, Captain? Because you knew I could do those things that you weren't capable of doing. Well, it worked. And you'll get what you want, a war between the Romulans and the Dominion. And if your conscience is bothering you, you should soothe it with the knowledge that you may have just saved the entire Alpha Quadrant and all it cost was the life of one Romulan senator, one criminal, and the self-respect of one Starfleet officer. I don't know about you, but I'd call that a bargain.

Comment: Biomimetic gel can be used "*to develop organic explosives*" but there's no evidence whatsoever that Garak had this in mind, nor that this is what he used it for.

Comment: @Valorum As stated in the same episode BASHIR: Captain, biomimetic gel is an extremely dangerous compound, as you know. I can't release it without at least some idea of where it's going. In the wrong hands, it could be used to make biogenic weapons, or for illegal replication experiments, or to develop organic explosives

Comment: Indeed, but does Garak even have the capability to develop organic explosives with it? It's certainly possible that Garak is lying, but the implication from Bashir is that in the wrong hands *and with significant medical knowledge* it can be put to the devil's work.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Garak isn't the one using it. Garak is basically asking for plutonium as currency to buy something he needs from a terrorist.

Comment: @NKCampbell Garek lies.  If the audience wasn't distracted by his claim he needs to make a deal - they and Sisko would have realized he was planning to make a bomb from the start.  It's expensive and explosive.  Garak does such a good job that people are still focused on expensive and not the fact he produced a bomb very conveniently.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - If he has access to a (presumably armed) Romulan shuttle, I'm guessing there's lots of explosive things there already.

Comment: There's nothing in the DS9 Companion to suggest that the bomb was made from the gel. It says that it was *"given to the rod's supplier"*